# displaySwitch.exe code replacement for windows (pre windows 7)

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp, delphi-7

I'm writing an app **I'd like to be backwardly compatible to some extent on XP, or at the very least windows vista.**

EDIT FOR CLARITY: I need to be able to do what the first code snippet below does, but in XP. **"Does anybody know the best approach to take under XP, given the functions aren't available in USER32.DLL.?"**

My initial prototype code on windows 7 just called CreateProcess to start up displayswitch.exe, which is deployed with windows 7.

if you are not familiar with it, it's a handy little utility that is what gets invoked when you press the windows key and the letter P. you can read [more about it here](http://www.missingremote.com/guide/tips-and-tweaks-simple-screen-switching-using-displayswitch).

while this was adequate, i subsequently needed to sense the current state (eg internal vs external or extend vs clone), so i have now coded up a winapi solution that works well on windows 7 (and i presume 8). it involves making calls to [SetDisplayConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [QueryDisplayConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in User32.DLL

The pertinent section of it is here (minus the many, many structures i had to hand craft in pascal code from the original klingon).

```
function getTopology : DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID ;
var  NumPathArrayElements,
   NumModeInfoArrayElements : UINT32;


var  PathArrayElements_Size,
   ModeInfoArrayElements_Size : UINT32;

error :  Longint;
paths :  PDISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO_array;
info  :  PDISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_array;
begin

    NumModeInfoArrayElements := 0;
    Result := DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_EXTERNAL;
    inc(result);

    error := GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT,NumPathArrayElements,NumModeInfoArrayElements);
    case error of
        ERROR_SUCCESS :
        begin

            PathArrayElements_Size := sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO) * NumPathArrayElements ;
            ModeInfoArrayElements_Size :=  sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO) * NumModeInfoArrayElements;

            GetMem(paths,PathArrayElements_Size);
            try
                GetMem(info,ModeInfoArrayElements_Size );
                try
                    error := QueryDisplayConfig(QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT,NumPathArrayElements, paths,NumModeInfoArrayElements, info,result);
                    case error of
                        ERROR_SUCCESS :;
                    else
                        Result := DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_EXTERNAL;
                        inc(result);
                    end;

                finally
                    FreeMem(info,ModeInfoArrayElements_Size );
                end;
            finally
                FreeMem(paths,PathArrayElements_Size);
            end;
        end;
    end;


end;



function setTopology ( top : DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID) : boolean;
var flags : dword;
begin
    result := false;
    flags := DecodeDISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID_SDC(top);
    if flags <> 0 then
    begin
        result := SetDisplayConfig(0,nil,0,nil,SDC_APPLY or flags) = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    end;
end;
```

Since these functions don't exist in XP (as far as I know), I am looking for a stable way of achieving a similar thing in XP. whilst i am coding in Delphi, it's not necessary that the solution be presented as such. i am quite happy to just look at how it's done, or read a description of the appropriate steps, and implement it myself.

(removed full listing as it was confusing the issue as it did not appear like a question)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: fair call. i have boldfaced the question, and reiterated it.

Comment: Why not to use [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413(v=vs.85).aspx) function ? For instance [`here`](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?318408-How-to-set-Extended-Desktop-using-WIN32-API&p=1049386#post1049386) is an example in klingon :-) It can set primary monitor and extend desktop.

Comment: Doh! I think it's a case of not seeing the wood for the trees. I have been using changedisplaysettings in 7 to adjust already attached monitors and was avoiding it in favour of the "proper method" for this task, however I can see now in xp there is no other option. Cheers. I don't mind Klingon, really.

Comment: Did you create a full Delphi solution for this? It'd be great if you could share your code! I'm trying to do the same and it would be great not having to reinvent the wheel. Thank you.